# Will space exploration be possible in a world without sand?

Tags: technology, civilization

Same Earth same timeline only difference there isn't even a grain of sand since the formation of planet Earth, can a civilization still be able to reach space age without the abundance of dirt cheap material to make semiconductor? I'm aware of other materials which can substitute silicon however they would be more expensive and uneconomic. What will the world look like today without GPS systems?

Comment: The absence of sand indicates some severe climate change compared to our world. Plus silicon exists in other form.

Comment: Will glass be available? What about [diatoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatom) that use silicon dioxide to build their cell walls?

Comment: @Victor Stafusa no natural sand, however we can make glass.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin yes we have other silicon compounds except silica. The problem is shortage of the element silicon due to lack of sand.

Comment: If there is no natural sand, grind down rock. Or wait for natural processes to do that. If there are no rocks, either, than "same earth same timeline" is absurd.

Comment: What makes you think especially early space exploration efforts were motivated by economic feasibility of any kind? There was an interview with one of the Apollo astronauts, I forgot where, who said that the real cost for them being on the Moon was about a million dollars -- then-dollars, that is -- per minute. I don't know if it's accurate, but it sounds like it would be in the ballpark. Miniturized computers being slightly more expensive than otherwise would not significantly change that figure.

Comment: @o.m. I do agree that statement is absurd but let's just say the condition here isn't favorable for the formation of sand.

Comment: @Michael Kjorling: A physicist(Michio Kaku) once said if you want to know how much it cost to put something into space just weight that thing in gold, on top of the cost we need to collect data both before and after launch. I mean without cheap transistors your rocket will be much too heavy with all the essential systems and not forget the expensive price tag.

Answer (score 4):

All sand is, is lots of tiny broken up rocks, and is created constantly by erosion. ( So if it doesn't exist, then either there's no erosion (no oceans, no running water) or no rocks. Rocks are created as a consequence of a planet existing and not being composed mostly of gases, so in order to not have rocks you'd need a very different type of planet from earth.

Click [here](http://www.beaufortcountylibrary.org/htdocs-sirsi/beachsan.htm) for a description of sand and its properties.

Most importantly though, sand is composed of the same elements (including silicon) as most other rocks, and therefore even if there was no erosion to make sand, we could just mine the bigger rocks themselves - in fact, that appears to be [mostly what we do](http://periodic.lanl.gov/14.shtml). Sand is a mixture of a bunch of types of rock, and so it isn't very pure; it's more efficient to mine quartz and use that to get silicon instead.

If we just didn't have much of the element silicon however, there are [many other elements and compounds we could use as semiconductors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_semiconductor_materials), but it would probably have slowed down the expansion of the computer industry greatly (which was vital for space travel), but it all most likely would have happened anyway. Essentially the only thing that would have changed (if we magically pretend the lack of silica didn't impact much else) would be it would take longer (maybe double, but that's just a guess) for the technology of the world to change from what it was in the beginning of the 1900's to what it is today. So the answer is that we'd be living the same way people lived 80-100 years ago, which isn't quite all that much of a change, relative to some of the other question on here. The rich would still be able to afford computers though, so it's possible that it would've widened the cultural rift between the wealthy and the poor. But eventually someone would've found a different semiconductor that's relatively cheap, and that rift would be diminished again (similar to the effect of automobiles [before and after the model T](http://www.wsj.com/articles/SB122246777029780525))

Answer (score 2):

If you remove sand from Earth when created, the human race would most likely have found something else. And would have used that other material to produce semiconductors... or some other sort of thing that could/would do the same.